# How to save web page locally in android?

Tags: android

I want to save simple text web page as html file in android and then show in webview.
The web page load first time from xml. then i want to download it and save it as html file.

But I want it at runtime to write data in a file and then show it in the app.
 it is possible.

thanks

Answer (score 6):

To save a webpage :

[saveWebArchive()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveWebArchive%28java.lang.String%29%29)

To load a webView already stored in assets

```
        WebView wv;  
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/youwebview.html");
```